# Automatically identify an unlabeled object from an image using bwperim

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

i would like to write an algorithm that allows me to automatically identify an unlabeled object from an image on matlab. So came across a suggestion that involves calculating the bwperim and simply filling in holes, however i dont quite understand how this works. I would really appreciate a point in the right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, here is [bwperim reference](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/bwperim.html).

It seems to return a b/w image, where the detected boundaries* are marked with white but it will not say which object is which (as it is quite tough decision), for that you need to come up with a representation.

As you may find "holes" in the boundary lines, 'growing' the lines could be necessary (see: "erode/dilate"). Then you could decide for a black area surrounded by white pixels, which you fill up with white, then again use erode to clear the other boundaries; labeling done.

(*) perimeter candidates of objects